# regex remove all text but string

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation

So I have a regex that matches to pull out data that I am looking for in text:

```
([A-Z]+A{5,})
```

This will select the code I am looking for in the following sample text:

```
Use these licenses with the VMware ESX build.

Feature               License Code                   Description
-------------------   ----------------------------   --------------------------------------------

CIFS                  CAYHXPKBFDUFZGABGAAAAAAAAAAA   CIFS protocol
FCP                   APTLYPKBFDUFZGABGAAAAAAAAAAA   Fibre Channel Protocol
```

My desired end result is to do a replace on the document that will yield a text document that contains the text

```
CAYHXPKBFDUFZGABGAAAAAAAAAAA,APTLYPKBFDUFZGABGAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: Find `([A-Z]+A{5,})(?!\Z)|.` and replace with `(?{1}$1,)`

Comment: @revo This is very clever, I think you should post it as an answer. I didn't know you could do something like `(?{1}` in the substitution. I would've written something like `.*?([A-Z]+A{5,})|\G.+\z` after enabling the "single line" option, but yours is better. I wonder if that lookahead is required though?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yes, that was redundant in its context. I removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an alternation to your regex like this:

```
([A-Z]+A{5,})|\X
```

Then replace it with:

```
(?1$1,)
```

Replacement string means, if first capturing group is matched replace it with `$1,` otherwise replace it with nothing.

In comments I added a negative lookahead to avoid adding comma after a matched sub-string if found at the end. But an extra trailing comma is inevitable with this regex.

---

A more better approach:

```
(\b[A-Z]++\b(?<=A{5}))|\X
```

This uses a possessive quantifier and a lookbehind for ending `A`s. You don't need to look for `A{5,}` but you only need to look for `A{5}`. Word boundaries could be removed if you want to match such strings even if found in middle of a longer word.

Comment: **EDIT:  Easier than I thought.  Just click check box . new line and your solution is perfect!
**
Very close and even a workable solution!  Thanks.  I do need to eliminate the carriage returns too so they are all on one line comma delimited, but I think I can figure that out.  Again thanks!